# com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8 vs com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8 - what's the difference?

Tags: oracle, gradle, jdbc, ojdbc

Using both in different modules of the application we faced the FAN issue:
`ERROR: attempt to configure ONS in FanManager failed with oracle.ons.NoServersAvailable: Subscription time out`
We're going to resolve it with the well-known recipe:

```
implementation("com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.8.0.0"){
    exclude(group = "com.oracle.ojdbc", module = "simplefan")
    exclude(group = "com.oracle.ojdbc", module = "ons")
}
```

But it should be understood the difference to unificate.
What's the difference? Thx!

Answer (score 2):

*ojdbc8* means the jar was compiled with Java 8 but it can be supported on recent JDKs.
*com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8* is the old coordinates of our bits on Maven Central
*com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8* is the new coordinates

Are both from 19.8.0.0?